# Index was outside the bounds of the array exception inside while loop

Tags: c#, math, primes

An exception:

> Index was outside the bounds of the array

gets thrown in the if below or the else below that

```
 public static Int64[] PrimeGenerator(Int64 length = 1)
{
    Int64 pos = 0;
    Int64[] primes = new Int64[length];
    Int64 Cprime = 2;
    Int64 controller = 0;//On evens it adds one less than, on odds it adds oone more than
    while(length >= 0)
    {
        if(pos == 0)
        {
            primes[pos] = 2;
            goto End;
        }
        if(controller % 2 == 0)
        {
            primes[pos] = (2 * Cprime - 1);
        }
        else
        {
            primes[pos] = (2 * Cprime + 1);
        }
        End:
        Cprime = primes[pos];
        controller++;
        pos++;
        length--;
    }
    return primes;
}
```

I have lookat the visual studio debugger and it says that Cprime is some crazy negative number and that length is 0 when it should not be

When I changed all the Int64's to UInt64's Cprime is some crazy positive integer and length is still zero

The code calling this code looks like this, print is a renamed Console.WriteLine

```
static void Main()
{
    UInt64 p = 1000;
    UInt64[] primes = PrimeGenerator(p);
    bool[] truth = BadArrayTest(primes);
    foreach(bool tru in truth)
    {
        print(tru);
    }
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(50000);
    Environment.Exit(0);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just do this

```
while(length > 0)
```

index is zero base that means starts from zero but length is not like that 
so you always have one more loop cycle which is out of array length.

Answer (score 0):

Your array is of `length`, but you run thru the loop `length+1` times. By the way, never ever use `Goto`.